# WFS service don't show a layer on QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, wfs

I have a map service running on ArcGIS Server based on MXD file (ArcMap), but when I try to connect on it from QGIS I get a message:

```
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" version="1.1.0" language="en">
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue">
<ows:ExceptionText>Table called GEO_ATP wasn't found.</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: What process do you follow in QGIS to connect to your map service.  What request was sent from QGIS?

Comment: What do you get in a browser when you send a WFS GetCapabilities request.?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS Server is QGIS consuming the Service from?